# JavaScript, Java, Php, or C++ cipher encryption - reworking algorithm

Tags: java, javascript, php, c++, encryption

I am trying to implement a loop that encrypts a string to the given shift amount of `int shift`. The code below works great, however I'd like to change the code so that it encrypts in a descending order instead of ascending. Any clues as to what to change in the algorithm?

```
int shift = 3;
string line = "abc";

for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

    if (line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z') {

        int rotate = line[i] + shift;
        if (rotate > 'z') line[i] = ((line[i] - 26) + shift);
        else line[i] = rotate;

    }

}

cout << line << endl;
```

With a shift of 3, the above code converts `string line` **"abc"** to **"def"**, but I am trying to get the output of **"dcb"**.

- NOTE: The code is in C++ but I will accept JavaScript, Java, or Php suggestions just as C++, as long as it's raw code with no library resources. Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure what you are implying. You can ignore that statement, that is for testing.

Comment: Ok. wasn't implying anything. Was suggesting a simple caesarian cipher can often be made easier with a key table twice as long you may first expect, as it saves many calculations internally, but its not really related to what you have posted now, so I dropped it.

Comment: Oh okay, but my code wraps A-z with: `line[i] = ((line[i] - 26) + key);` so that is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just upgrade the variable shift and then instead of checking overflow of increasing check the decreasing

```
int shift = -3;
string line = "abc";

for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

    if (line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z') {



        int rotate = line[i] + shift;
        if (rotate < 'a') line[i] = ((line[i] + 26) + shift);
        else line[i] = rotate;

    }

}

cout << line << endl;
```

you can also do the below if in your loop if you want to handle uppercases

```
if (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z') {

        int rotate = line[i] + shift;
        if (rotate < 'A') line[i] = ((line[i] + 26) + shift);
        else line[i] = rotate;

    }
```